# How to compare previous selected node with current selected node on asp.net treeview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, treeview

I want to compare last selected node and current selected node on the treeview by using java script.

Please suggest me with some code samples to compare last selection and current selection node on the treeview.

If both the node selections are same , we need to deselect the same node.

Thanks. Please help on this.

I have resolved by server side code:

```
 protected void TreeView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ADUtility.treenodevalue))
            {
                if (ADUtility.treenodevalue == TreeView1.SelectedNode.ValuePath)
                {
                    TreeView1.SelectedNode.Selected = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    ADUtility.treenodevalue = TreeView1.SelectedNode.ValuePath;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ADUtility.treenodevalue = TreeView1.SelectedNode.ValuePath;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008522/1264217

Comment: @ZaidIqbal: I looked in that URL but we need to get the previous selected node value. That reference link will get only the current node not previous selected node.

Answer (score -1):

I am just giving you the Pseudo code for this after that you can implement it by own.
Make 2 Global variables CurrentselectedNode and PreviousselectedNode
And make a ArrayList of Nodes

```
Arraylist<Object> nodeCollection;
var PreviousselectedNode;
var CurrentselectedNode;

if(nodeCollection.Current != null)
{
    PreviousselectedNode= nodeCollection.Current;
    var tempselectedItem = Products_Data.selectedNodeID.value;
    var CurrentselectedNode = Document.getElementById(tempselectedItem);

// Here Do what you want to do with current Node and Previous Node

    nodeCollection.Add(tempselectedNode);
}
else
{
    var tempselectedItem = Products_Data.selectedNodeID.value;
    var tempselectedNode = Document.getElementById(tempselectedItem);
    nodeCollection.Add(tempselectedNode);
}
```

Comment: Mark it as answer and click on upper arrow if it gives you any idea about yours solution.